# Getting the difference of two dataframes in R

Tags: r

If, I have two dataframes each containing 12 columns and have 4781 and 4807 rows respectively, then, I want the intersection of these two dataframes. I did use the compare command in the compare package, and I found that one is a subset of another. But, how do I get the difference of the two? Thanks!

If a1 and a2 are the two dataframes, then,

```
class(a1)     class(a1$V1)
data.frame    factor

class(a2)     class(a2$V1)
data.frame    factor
```

I need those elements which are present in the bigger dataframe and not in the other dataframe

Comment: Could you provide reproducible data? Meanwhile I think you want to try `intersect()`.

Comment: I have added the link for the two files. Also, intersect works on vectors, I guess.

Comment: @chan chong You can use `intersect` from `dplyr` which works on data.frames.

Comment: You could provide reproducible data for this by creating a couple of ~10 line data frames within your question, for illustration purposes, rather than us have to download some text files and then work out the exact read.csv call...

Comment: @chanchong I see 4470 rows after using `intersect()`. I think `intersect()` is working for you. @akrun Thanks for providing additional info.

Comment: If A1 **is a subset** of A2, then A1 **is the common elements**. Problem solved

Comment: A1 is also the **intersection** if A1 is a subset of A2. Maybe you don't mean subset.

Comment: I meant, I need those elements which are present in the bigger dataframe and not in the other dataframe. My bad for poor choice of words.

Comment: Are all your rows unique? If not, how many copies of duplicated rows do you want in your output?

Comment: Yes, all rows across the 10 columns are unique.

Answer (score 1):

Test data set:

```
> aa = data.frame(x=1:10,y=letters[1:10])
```

split into two overlapping data frames. These are like your data - there's some rows common to each and some rows unique to each:

```
> a1 = aa[1:8,]
> a2 = aa[5:10,]
> a1
  x y
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c
4 4 d
5 5 e
6 6 f
7 7 g
8 8 h
> a2
    x y
5   5 e
6   6 f
7   7 g
8   8 h
9   9 i
10 10 j
```

Then use `dplyr` operators:

Unique to a2:

```
> dplyr::setdiff(a2,a1)
   x y
1  9 i
2 10 j
```

That might be what you want. I'll illustrate some other set operations anyway:

Unique to a1:

```
> dplyr::setdiff(a1,a2)
  x y
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c
4 4 d
```

in both:

```
> intersect(a1,a2)
  x y
1 5 e
2 6 f
3 7 g
4 8 h
```

Those are the three parts of the Venn diagram of `a1` and `a2`. So if we put those three parts together we should get our whole set back:

```
> rbind(setdiff(a1,a2), intersect(a1,a2), setdiff(a2,a1)) ==  aa
      x    y
1  TRUE TRUE
2  TRUE TRUE
3  TRUE TRUE
4  TRUE TRUE
5  TRUE TRUE
6  TRUE TRUE
7  TRUE TRUE
8  TRUE TRUE
9  TRUE TRUE
10 TRUE TRUE
```